# Error when defining iterator/iterator constructor?

Tags: java

I get an error when I try return new MyIterator() and I'm not sure what to do with the MyIterator constructor (have to define iterator based on a start node parameter). Any idea how to fix this? I know how to implement the next and hasNext.

I think I solved it....Thanks!!

Comment: Provide it with the start node..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining a single constructor for your iterator, `MyIterator(MyListNode<E> start)`. From your code, it's clear that the `MyListNode<E> start` argument is missing.

What I mean is, in this line:

```
return new MyIterator();
```

... you need to pass a reference to the first node in the list, something like this:

```
return new MyIterator(firstNode);  // replace firstNode with the actual value
```

Comment: I have not written code in the constructor....I do not know what to do with it.  What do I do with the parameter...

Comment: When you call `return new MyIterator();` you MUST pass as an argument a reference to the first node of the list, because that's how you defined the constructor. What to do with the first node, inside the Iterator? that's a different question. Hint: you need to store it in an attribute and make sure to implement `hasNext` and `next` accordingly.